How many regions are needed to divide the spherical section $\{r \leq |x| < r+1\}$?
Consider the space $\mathbb{R}^k$ and the spherical section $S_r:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^k:r\leq |x|< r+1\}$.
Divide the section into $N$ subregions each with diameter at most $d$. I am asking the least possible $N$ such that the subdivision can be accomplished.
This problem comes from the proof of Thm. I.5.1. of Statistical Estimation: Asymptotic Theory. The author stated that it is possible to accomplish this with $N\leq Cr/d^{k-1}$, where $C$ is a positive constant. However, he did not explain why.
I believe the statement may contain a typo. Clearly, for $k=1$, it is not possible to divide the interval $(-(r+1),-r]\cup [r,r+1)$ with $N\leq Cr$ (which does not depend on $d$) regions. The least number should be $N=2/d$ (an even partition).
Furthermore, this problem is related to the Equal Partition of the Unit Sphere, where the author shows that it is possible to partite the unit sphere with $N$ equal diameter regions for $N=O(1/d^k)$. So I conjecture to divide a spherical section, we at least need $N=O(Cr/d^{k+1})$ regions, where the extra $1/d$ comes from partiting the radial direction into $1/d$ uniform bins (so that we may can use the Triangle inequality to show the max diameter of the subregions are $2d$).
